# Code weaving in XAML controls

Tags: c#, user-controls, winrt-xaml, compile-time-weaving

I am developing user controls for winRT app. I want to avoid massive repetition of code and I am wondering if you know any solution for code weaving for properties and dependency property? I've tried Fody, but it doesn't work well with dependency properties. I just want my code to be more smooth and more clear for reading and writing.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what your repetition is:

- Are you using multiple GridViews/Listview that are using the same ItemTemplate? if that is the case then create a  DataTemplate with your code inside it.
- Are you going to show the same kind of information outside a GridView/ListView over and over, maybe look into creating a UserControl?